# Cakephp 2.0, CPanel and Shell scripts

Tags: php, cakephp, cron, cpanel, cakephp-2.0

I have cPanel on a shared server and I need to run a shell script everyday.

This script has to call a controller function that scraps a webpage everyday.

My problem is that I don't know how to do a shell script that calls this function and add it at cron jobs in cpanel. How do I do all of this?

Thanks in advance!

---

I'm going to extend my question.

I have this code "TestTask.php":

```
class TestTask extends Shell {

    function main() {
         $this->out('Hello world.');
    }

    function execute() {
         $this->out('Hello world 2.');
    }
}
```

It's located in: `/home/myuser/public_html/app/Console/Command/Task`

And then, my cronjob is like this:

```
* * * * * php /home/myuser/public_html/app/Console/cake.php test -app /home/myuser/public_html/app >> /home/myuser/public_html/file.log
```

The last part it's to log the output in a file.

It doesn't work at all.

Help please!!!

Comment: If you have ssh access, I think you can do it with crontab -e command.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the command for a cron job I am using on my server:

`/home/path-to-cake/lib/Cake/Console/cake -app /home/path-to-cake/app time`

where `time` is my shell, located in `/app/Console/Command/TimeShell.php`. This is how you run shells.

Now, on the other part of your question, a task must be called from within a shell. From the code you posted, it seems that you are confusing a bit shells with tasks. A shell can contain tasks, just like controllers can have components. `main();` is required for a shell when it is called without any arguments. It is not necessary for a task to implement it. On the other hand, a task must implement an `execute();` method.

In order to run a task from your shell, be sure to add `public $tasks = array('Test');` in the `TestShell` class; You can use this task in your shell just like you use a component in a controller: `$this->Test->whatever();`

For more info on CakePHP 2.0 shells and tasks, have a look [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#shell-tasks)

Hope this helped!